# Not able to update tinyint field

Tags: java, hibernate, tinyint

Hi I am not able to update msgFromUserFlag in database through hibernate. Neither i am getting any error while updating this value.

This is my code at DAO layer. and in database my field is of TINYINT(1) type and in persistence class it is of type boolean.

```
public void updateMsgFromUserFlag(CustomerOrder customerOrderEntity){
    try {

        //update(customerOrderEntity);
        final StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer("update CustomerOrder custOrder set custOrder.msgFromUserFlag = :param1 where custOrder.goldOrderNumber = :param2");
        final Query query = this.getEm().createQuery(queryString.toString());
        query.setParameter("param1",customerOrderEntity.isMsgFromUserFlag());
        query.setParameter("param2", customerOrderEntity.getGoldOrderNumber());
        int modification=query.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(PersistenceException ex) {
        otLogger.debug("OrderDaoImpl.exception occurred "+ex);
        throw new TechnicalException(Constants.ERROR_HIBERNATE_EXCEPTION, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us some portion of entity and mappiing

Comment: @Column
 private boolean msgFromUserFlag=false; This is my entity code.

Comment: I'm wondering why can't you make an object CustomerOrder and make neccessay changes to it and call update or  saveOrUpdate method

Comment: in your code you try update all records where param1 and param2. @Arun Sudhakaran  is right

Comment: Sorry i dint get your last comment , i tried creating object as well but its not updating.

Answer (score 0):

I think your property is something like

```
private boolean msgFromUserFlag=false;
```

and the getters and setters were produced by eclipse itself, which will generate them like

```
public boolean isMsgFromUserFlag() {
    return msgFromUserFlag;
}

public void setMsgFromUserFlag(boolean msgFromUserFlag) {
    this.msgFromUserFlag = msgFromUserFlag;
}
```

You can try changing the getter to `getMsgFromUserFlag()`, because wrong getter methods sometimes causes `Mapping Exception` while publishing the project.